# Returning NULL from a getNext(), getPrev() or getData() function in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, null, nodes

I am trying to create a linked list and am currently testing a print function but in order to print all the nodes in the list, I need to know the length.

In order to find the length, I need to use a for loop to cycle from head to whenever current is NULL (aka tail).

The issue is whenever a node in the list is set to NULL, it causes an error or nothing happens when I use getNext() or any of the other functions that are meant to return NULL.

I have tried for a long time to figure this out but I simply can't find what I'm doing wrong. It's probably a dumb mistake but I just can't find it.

Creating a new blank list:

```
LL::LL()
{
    // These are all protected variables
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    current = NULL;
}
```

Creating a new blank node:

```
Node::Node()
{
    // These are all protected variables
    data = v_t(); // Value_Type
    prev = NULL;
    next = NULL;
}
```

Creating a new node with arguments:

```
Node::Node(const v_t& d, Node* n, Node* p)
{
    data = d;
    prev = p;
    next = n;
}
```

Length function:

```
int LL::length()
{
    int answer = 0;
    for (current = head; current != NULL; current = current->getNext())
    {
        answer++;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Adding a new node to the tail of the list:

```
void LL::addToTail(const v_t& item)
{
    // ------------(data, next, prev)
    tail = new Node(item, NULL, tail);

    if (tail -> getPrev() != NULL)
    {
        tail -> getPrev() -> setNext(tail);
    }

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = tail;
    }
}
```

Next return function:

```
Node* Node::getNext() const
{
    return next;
}
```

These are in the same format for the other two getters.

Below is the full classes:

node.h

```
#ifndef CHRIS_NODE
#define CHRIS_NODE

#include "account.h"

class Node
{
    public: // Members that are externally visible

        typedef Account v_t;

        // Default Constructor
        Node();
        Node(const v_t& d, Node* n, Node* p);

        // Destructor
        ~Node();

        // Pointer Getters and Setters
        void setNext(Node* n);
        void setPrev(Node* p);
        Node* getNext() const;
        Node* getPrev() const;

        // Data Getters and Setters
        void setData(v_t& d);
        v_t getData() const;

    private: // Members that are internally visible

        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
        v_t data;

};

#endif
```

node.cpp

```
#include"node.h"

Node::Node()
{
    data = v_t();
    prev = NULL;
    next = NULL;
}

Node::Node(const v_t& d, Node* n, Node* p)
{
    data = d;
    prev = p;
    next = n;
}

Node::~Node(){};

void Node::setNext(Node* n)
{
    next = n;
}

void Node::setPrev(Node* p)
{
    prev = p;
}

Node* Node::getNext() const
{
    return next;
}

Node* Node::getPrev() const
{
    return prev;
}

void Node::setData(v_t& d)
{
    data = d;
}

Node::v_t Node::getData() const
{
    return data;
}
```

linklist.h

```
#ifndef CHRIS_LIST
#define CHRIS_LIST

#include "node.h"

class LL
{
    public: // Members that are externally visible
    typedef Node::v_t v_t;

    LL();
    LL(Node*  h, Node* t, Node* c);
    ~LL();

    int length();

    void addToHead(const v_t& item);

    void addToCurrent(const v_t& item);

    void addToTail(const v_t& item);

    bool search(const v_t& target);

    void removeHead();

    void removeCurrent();

    void removeTail();

    void clear();

    void printList();

    protected: // Members that are internally visible
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    Node* current;
};


#endif
```

linklist.cpp

```
#include "linklist.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

LL::LL()
{
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    current = NULL;
}

LL::LL(Node*  h, Node* t, Node* c)
{
    head = h;
    tail = t;
    current = c;
}

LL::~LL()
{
    clear();
        
}

int LL::length()
{
    int answer = 0;
    for (current = head; current != NULL; current = current->getNext())
    {
        answer++;
    }
    return answer;
}

void LL::addToHead(const v_t& item)
{
    head = new Node(item, head, NULL);

    if (head -> getNext() != NULL)
    {
        head -> getNext() -> setPrev(head);
    }

    if (tail == NULL)
    {
        tail = head;
    }
}

void LL::addToCurrent(const v_t& item)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node(item, current, current->getPrev());
    current->setPrev(newNode);
    newNode->getPrev()->setNext(newNode);
    current = head;
}

void LL::addToTail(const v_t& item)
{
    tail = new Node(item, NULL, tail);

    if (tail -> getPrev() != NULL)
    {
        tail -> getPrev() -> setNext(tail);
    }

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = tail;
    }
}

bool LL::search(const v_t& target)
{
    for (current = head; current != NULL; current = current -> getNext())
    {
        if (target == (current -> getData()))
        {
            cout << "The data is stored in " << current << "." << endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void LL::removeHead()
{
    Node* temp = head;
    head = head -> getNext();
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        head -> setPrev(NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        tail = NULL;
    }
    delete temp;
}

void LL::removeCurrent()
{
    if (current == head) 
    {
        removeHead();
    }
    else if (current == tail)
    {
        removeTail();
    }

    current -> getNext() -> setPrev(current -> getPrev());
    current -> getPrev() -> setNext(current -> getNext());

    delete current;
    current = head;
}

void LL::removeTail()
{
    Node* temp = tail;
    tail = tail -> getPrev();
    if (tail != NULL)
    {
        tail -> setNext(NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        head = NULL;
    }
    delete temp;
}

void LL::clear()
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        removeHead();
    }
}

void LL::printList()
{
    if (LL::length() == 0)
    {
        cout << "List Empty.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        current = head;

        for (int i = 1; i <= LL::length(); i++)
        {
            if (current != NULL)
            {
                cout << "Node " << i << ": " << current -> getData() << endl;
                current = current -> getNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

account.h

```
#ifndef CHRIS_ACCOUNT
#define CHRIS_ACCOUNT

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Account
{
public:
    // Members that are externally visible

    // These are member functions

    // Constructor
    // Precondition:    none
    // Postcondition:   A new instance of account is created and its 
    //                  instance data initialsed to either zero or a 
    //                  parameter-provided value
    Account(const string nm = "", const double initialValue = 0.0);

    // Members that mutate data

    // Precondition:    acct_balance has been initialised
    // Postcondition:   amount is added to the acct_balance
    void deposit(const double amount);

    // Precondition:    acct_balance has been initialised
    // Postcondition:   amount is subtracted from the acct_balance
    void withdraw(const double amount);

    void setName(const string nm);

    // Members that query data

    // Precondition:    acct_balance has been initialised
    // Postcondition:   The value of acct_balance is returned
    double balance() const;

    // Precondition:    acct_balance has been initialised
    // Postcondition:   Returns true if acct_balance is greater 
    //                  than zero, false otherwise
    bool has_funds() const;

    string getName() const;


private:

    double acc_balance;
    string name;
};

bool operator == (Account acc1, Account acc2);

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Account acc);

// close the macroguard
#endif
```

account.cpp

```
#include "Account.h"

Account::Account(string nm, double initialValue)
{
    acc_balance = initialValue;
    name = nm;
}

void Account::deposit(double amount)
{
    acc_balance += amount;
}

void Account::withdraw(double amount)
{
    acc_balance -= amount;
}

double Account::balance() const
{
    return acc_balance;
}

bool Account::has_funds() const
{
    if (acc_balance > 0.0) 
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

string Account::getName() const
{
    return name;
}

void Account::setName(string nm) 
{
    name = nm;
}

bool operator == (Account acc1, Account acc2)
{
    if (acc1.getName() == acc2.getName() && acc1.balance() == acc2.balance())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Account acc)
{
    out << "(" << acc.getName() << ", " << acc.balance() << ")\n";
    return out;
}
```

bank.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "Account.h"
#include "node.h"
#include "linklist.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   int amount = 0;

   cout << "How many accounts?\n";
   cin >> amount;

   LL* LL1 = new LL();

   for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++)
   {
       string nm;
       double iv;

       cout << "What is the name for account " << i << "?\n";
       cin >> nm;
       cout << "What is the initial value for account " << i << "?\n";
       cin >> iv;

       Account newAcc(nm, iv);
       LL1 -> addToTail(newAcc);
   }

    LL1 -> printList();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Let me know if you need any more information or code :)

Comment: "_Let me know if you need any more information or code_" - The question would be clearer if you showed the full definition of your classes.

Comment: Since `new Node(item, NULL, tail);` does not match against the only constructor you chose to show us, you probably need to add that ctor in as well. In fact, include a proper [mcve] and static-code the node insertions that are griefing you.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I would but I thought these snippets should be enough for what I'm asking without overcomplicating the post with unnecessary code. But as I said if you think there is some helpful code missing or you think i should just post the entire class let me know.

Comment: @WhozCraig My bad. I added the correct node constructor this time.

Comment: `for (current = head; current != NULL; current->getNext())` is an infinite loop because you forgot to write `current =`. Don't overthink it.

Comment: Why is `current` declared in class scope instead of function scope? Is there any reason you'll want to share this value with other functions, even though it ends up null at the end of the function? This just prevents you from making the function `const` (once implemented correctly) for no real benefit. Furthermore `nullptr` is preferrable to `NULL` in C++. Btw: Imho it's preferrable to separate the iteration functionality to a seperate `LLIterator` class.

Comment: @user253751 Yeah this is always the case. Thank you. Although this does not fix the null pointer issue.

Comment: @fabian I'm not sure what you mean, could you maybe use code snippets? Thanks though :)

Comment: Since this is impossible to put into a comment I've created an example. Note that the implementation is far from complete/polished: https://github.com/Mondlied/cpp_samples/blob/main/collections/linked_list/LinkedList.hpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nothing happens when I use `getNext()` or any of the other functions that are meant to return NULL.

That is because you did not *use* the result of `getNext()` in your `length` method. Your loop never assigns a new reference to `current`. Change this:

```
for (current = head; current != NULL; current->getNext())
```

to:

```
for (current = head; current != NULL; current = current->getNext())
```

It is an antipattern to define `current` as an instance member of the `LL` class. Such a reference should be a local variable, defined in the functions that need it. It should not be part of the *state* of your linked list.

So wherever you use `current`, define it as a local variable:

```
Node * current = head;
```

> in order to print all the nodes in the list, I need to know the length.

Not necessarily. You could change your `printList` function to work without `length`:

```
void LL::printList()
{
    Node * current = head;
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        cout << "List Empty.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; current != NULL; i++, current = current -> getNext())
        {
            cout << "Node " << i << ": " << current -> getData() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

If you keep the version where you call `length` and keep using the instance variable `current`, then the loop will not loop, because the call to `length()` will alter `current` (after your initialisation), and set it to `NULL`.

If you really want to have the instance variable `current`, then only change it in the places where it really needs to be *set*, like in `search`. But it shouldn't be altered by `length()` or `printList()`, which are not supposed to change the *state* of your instance. So in `length()` and `printList()` you should use a *local* variable, not the *instance* variable.

Comment: Why does creating current in the class scope not work? Since I want to keep track of the current pointer in the list class and I use it currently in practically every function. Also the first issue has been fixed but it still outputs an empty field then crashes.

Comment: *"Why does creating current in the class scope not work?"*: it does work; it just is not good practice. *"I want to keep track of the current pointer in the list class"*: but actually you don't, because your functions will just iterate until `current` is `null`. So that is not very helpful in tracking. You'll always find it `null`. If you have an empty field in the output, you did something else wrong. You posted about 400 lines of code. I don't feel like reviewing that. Only pointed to the obvious mistake.

Comment: May I propose you trim down your code to not use `Account`, but plain integers, until you have it working. Only then extend back to using `Account`. Start simple, make sure it works, only then extend a bit. Test again. If it works... extend further. 400 lines of code when your problem is about printing a linked list, is doing it the wrong way. You can write 50 lines of code for a simple linked list that can print. Then extend.

Comment: See addition to answer. I hope it makes more clear why  your print loop doesn't loop when you stick to using a `current` instance member, which you use in almost all methods.

Comment: Ok, so the way you work is to read answers and then use it to correct your question's code and post your own answer which essentially uses what is in the comments and answers? That is not very considerate to people who spent time on your question.

Comment: I apologise. I see that your addition to the question which I did not see before. I have set your response as the official answer. Thank you.